# Stata: identify consecutive rows with numbers that can cancel out

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in long form that lists observations by month. I want to identify if consecutive rows for a variable can cancel out (in other words, have the same absolute value). And if so, I want to change both observations to zero. In addition, I want to have an additional dummy variable that tells me if I've changed anything for that row. How can I structure the code?

For example,

```
Date       Var1      Var 2
Jan2010     5          6
Feb2010     6          0
Mar2010    -6          1
```

In the above example, I want to make the dataset into below

```
Date       Var1      Var 2     Dummy
Jan2010     5          6        0
Feb2010     0          0        1
Mar2010     0          0        1
```

Comment: The problem is ill posed. As @Brendan wonders in his answer, what happens if `Apr2010` is `6`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My data does not come with the above scenario, which is why I didn't take that into consideration when asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (seemingly) meets the criteria described, but other considerations may come into play if there are other factors not explicitly mentioned (*e.g.*, do you need to consider whether `Var2` "cancels out"? What if `Apr2010` is `6`? *etc.*).

```
clear
input str7 Date Var1 Var2
"Jan2010"     5          6
"Feb2010"     6          0
"Mar2010"    -6          1
end

gen Dummy = Var1 == Var1[_n+1] * -1 | Var1 == Var1[_n-1] * -1

replace Var1 = 0 if Dummy
replace Var2 = 0 if Dummy

li , noobs
```

yielding

```
+-------------------------------+
|    Date   Var1   Var2   Dummy |
|-------------------------------|
| Jan2010      5      6       0 |
| Feb2010      0      0       1 |
| Mar2010      0      0       1 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Or perhaps more correctly, `Dummy` should be generated with respect to actual months and not observations:

```
gen Month = monthly(Date, "MY")
format Month %tm
tsset Month , monthly

gen Dummy = Var1 == Var1[_n+1] * -1 | Var1 == Var1[_n-1] * -1
```

**Edit**: As Roberto rightly points out, the previous code (using `abs()`) was written based on the example posted, but multiplying by `-1` is more robust and yields the same result (for the sample data posted). And the suggestion to preserve the original variables is of course a generally good idea.

Comment: One error, one suggestion. Using `abs()` seems wrong. You will make zero not only consecutive pairs `(x, -x)` or `(-x, x)`, but also pairs `(x, x)` and `(-x, -x)`. The original post, mistakenly, implies that the sum of values that have the same absolute value, cancel out. This of course is not true. To create the indicator variable (you call it dummy) something like `... Var1 == Var1[_n+1] * -1 ...` should work. The suggestion is to make a copy of the original variable to be `replace`d. It's usually a good idea to keep originals around. `clonevar` is a good choice.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer: Good points; thanks. I took the `abs()` approach based on the wording in the original question & example posted, but of course you are correct in your assessment that this returns `TRUE` when the values don't actually "cancel out".

Comment: Thanks@brendan @RobertoFerrer for help! The above code solves my problem.